# Anchor links are not working properly with Barba.js(v2)

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, barbajs

I have this example page where I'm testing Barba.js(v2). I'm building this page locally with virtual host. The transition I made with Barba.js seems to be working fine, but the issue I'm facing is that anchor links are not working properly. For example, when I click either "ABOUT" menu in header or ABOUT button next to the image, the transition starts, but the page somehow automatically redirects to home.

Here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body data-barba="wrapper">

<ul class="transition">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
        <div class="left">
            <h1>Hello There.</h1>
            <a href="/about/" class="cta">About</a>
        </div>
        <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="man">

    </main>
    </div>
<!-- Barba Core -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
<!-- GSAP for animation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS

```
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height:100%;
    }

body {
        font-family:$body-font;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:1em;
        color:#333;
        height:100vh;
        background-color:#F4F4F4;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
    padding:0;
    margin-right:auto;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

li a{
    margin-right:2em;
}

h1{
    font-size:3em;
    margin-top:1.5em;
}

.cta{
    display:block;
    padding:2em 2em 2em 0;
    font-size:1.4em;
}

img{
    width:100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);

}

ul.transition{
    display:flex;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    pointer-events:none;
}

ul.transition li{
    transform: scaleY(0);
    background:#fff;
    width:20%;
}

@media (min-width:650px){
    main{
        display:flex;
        margin-top:3em;
        position:relative;
        z-index:3;
    }

    .wrapper{
        max-width:950px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .left{
        padding-right:2em;
    }

    img{
        width:400px;
    }

    .cta{
        padding:1em;
        background:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:21 !important;
        width:80%;
        animation-fill-mode:initial;

    }
}
```

Lastly, js

```
function pageTransition() {

    var tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: .5, scaleY: 1, transformOrigin: "bottom left", stagger: .2});
    tl.to('ul.transition li', { duration: .5, scaleY: 0, transformOrigin: "bottom left", stagger: .1, delay: .1});
  }


  function contentAnimation() {

    var tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.from('.left', { duration: 1.5, translateY: 50, opacity: 0});
    tl.to('img', { clipPath:"polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)"}, "-=1.1");

  }

  function delay(n) {
    n = n || 2000;
    return new Promise(done => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        done();
      }, n);
    });
  }

    barba.init({

      sync: true,

      transitions: [{

        async leave(data) {

          const done = this.async();

          pageTransition();
          await delay(1500);
          done();

        },

        async enter(data) {
          contentAnimation();
        },

        async once(data) {
          contentAnimation();
        }

      }]
    });
```

I haven't seen this kind of issue, and honestly I have no idea how to fix this. I'm assuming it has something to do with Barba.js, possibly back end, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe [one of the threads on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/search/?q=barba&quick=1) can help you set it up correctly.

Comment: @ZachSaucier  I believe I set it up correctly, because like I said in the post, the transition is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to test your links by changing them to index.html or about.html. If you follow online Youtube videos for learning, I recommend going back and re-watching to see if you made code errors.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```